# (InvalidParameterValue) CopyDBClusterSnapshot operation: PreSignedUrl could not be authenticated while copying encrypted cluster cross region

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Can anyone please review this code snippet and explain what is missing? According to the official documentation, we just need to add source_region which automatically creates the URL. But that fails with the same error.
So, I have added a code to generate the url and then call the copy_db_cluster_snapshot but no luck with the error.

```
dest_rds_client = boto3.client('rds', region_name='eu-central-1')
pre_signed_url = dest_rds_client.generate_presigned_url\
            ('copy_db_cluster_snapshot', Params={'KmsKeyId': key,
                                                 'SourceDBClusterSnapshotIdentifier':'test',
                                                 'TargetDBClusterSnapshotIdentifier':'test',
                                                 'SourceRegion': 'us-west-2'},
             ExpiresIn=1000)
dest_rds_client.copy_db_cluster_snapshot(SourceDBClusterSnapshotIdentifier='test',
                                                     TargetDBClusterSnapshotIdentifier='test',
                                                     KmsKeyId=key,
                                                     PreSignedUrl=pre_signed_url)
```

Comment: if there is an error, could you please post it as well?

Comment: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CopyDBClusterSnapshot operation: PreSignedUrl could not be authenticated.